# Hello Watch 3+ firmware extracting

Tags: binary, binaryfiles, binary-data, firmware, binwalk

I have a firmware file of Hello Watch 3+ smart watch. I want to customize this firmware. I tried binwalk but no result. I am trying reverse engineering for the first time. Can you help me?

I tried to extract the bin file with binwalk. I tried to convert the bin file to iso but no luck.

```
$ binwalk -Me M78_4.00.13_231205.bin                   

Scan Time:     2023-12-07 06:37:15
Target File:   /home/kali/Desktop/bins/M78_4.00.13_231205.bin
MD5 Checksum:  e39e4a9488b26196bc9bde668502284f
Signatures:    411

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```